# Single Signin for multiple sites

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I have `domain1.com` with a login screen and have `domain2.com` with another login screen `login.php`

While user accessing `domain2.com`, if he already logged in to the `domain1.com`, the request should be redirect to the `domain2.com\index.php`

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do in normal way using cookies and sessions.

For cross domain login, This is how Stackoverlow sites did.
read [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) and [yet this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274)